# Is it possible to re-try a try-catch block if error is thrown - JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, loops, error-handling, try-catch

lets say i have a function that gets a random number, then returns wether that number meets a condition and if not it throws an error:

```
const randFunc = () => {
 let a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
 
 if(a === 5){
     return a
  } else {
     throw new Error('Wrong Num')
 }
}
```

what i would like to know is if i can loop through this function until i get '5'

```
try {
    randFunc()
} catch {
    //if error is caught it re-trys
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Put it into a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an standard endless loop:

```js
const randFunc = () => {
 let a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
 
 if(a === 5){
     return a;
  } else {
     throw new Error('Wrong Num');
 }
}

function untilSuccess() {
  while (true) {
    try {
      return randFunc();
    } catch {}
  }
}

console.log(untilSuccess());
```

Or a recursive option:

```js
const randFunc = () => {
  let a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);

  if (a === 5) {
    return a;
  } else {
    throw new Error('Wrong Num');
  }
}

function untilSuccess() {
  try {
    return randFunc();
  } catch {
    return untilSuccess();
  }
}

console.log(untilSuccess());
```

This one can blow your stack, depending on your retries (not so much of a problem for this though).

Comment: Thanks Alot, this helped solve it good to know didnt think of a while loop!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work for you

```
let success = false;
while (!success) {
  try {
    randFunc();
    success = true;
  } catch { }
}
```

This code will cause an endless loop if randFunc() keeps throwing.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a [recursive function](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-recursive-function/) to keep trying something until it works:

```
const randFunc = () => {
 let a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
 
 if(a === 5){
     return a
  } else {
     throw new Error('Wrong Num')
 }
}

getfive()

//getfive is recursive and will call itself until it gets a success
function getfive(){
  try{
    randFunc()
    console.log('GOT 5!')
  }
  catch(err){
    console.log('DID NOT GET 5')
    getfive()
  }
}
```